# Teleporting entities (minecraft)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need some help

I have a system set up that teleports an entity to an arrow, but the entity keeps getting stuck on the arrow and stopping it from moving.

```
/execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~-2 ~ /tp @e[type=squid] @e[type=arrow]
```

Is there a way to get the squid 1 block under or above the arrow BEFORE the arrow can hit the squid?

I'm currently using Minecraft version 1.11.2 if that affects anything, thanks for the help in advance <3

Answer (score 1):

The `/teleport` command lets you specify coordinates relative to the executer (in this case, the arrow).

The following command will make the arrow constantly teleport the squid a block above it:

```
/execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ /teleport @e[type=squid] ~ ~1 ~
```